# How to interpret this C++ type?

Tags: c++, gcc, types

Today I was helping with following incorrect code piece (`func` was declared with `int` param, but `int*` was passed as second param to `std::thread` constructor):

```
#include <thread>

void func(int);
int* ptr;

void start()
{
    std::thread t = std::thread(func, ptr);
}
```

When I tried to compile this with gcc 5.3.0, it printed error message with following type:

```
class std::result_of<void (*(int*))(int)>
```

Now I wonder how to interpret type passed as parameter to `class std::result_of<>`. It is similar to pointer to function (in this case `void(*)(int)`), but with extra `(int*)` after star in brackets. How to interpret this type?

Comment: If `func` requires an `int` why are you passing an `int*`?

Comment: This was an error in code which I saw today - probably this was a typo.

Comment: A similar statement gives [this according to cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28*f%28int*%29%29%28int%29).

Comment: [How to interpret complex C/C++ declarations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations)

Comment: At first I though that the compiler refused to accept this declaration - is my assumption right? Can you maybe give us the full error message gcc printed for clarity?

Comment: Error message was confusing - most important part was "error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(int*))(int)>’". So this is completely different from usual "invalid conversion from X to Y" or "no matching function for call to X()".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void (*(int*))(int)
```

Is:

a function that takes a single parameter of type `int*` as returns

a pointer to a function that takes a single parameter of type `int` and returns

`void`

---

It is similar to the C/C++ standard library function [signal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/):

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

which returns a pointer to a previous signal handler (which is of the same type as the `func` parameter).

EDIT: As [Pete Becker pointed out in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37844752/how-to-interpret-this-c-type/37845022?noredirect=1#comment63150828_37845022), when used with `std::result_of`, it [means something different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37845242/4932834), but type of expression itself is still the type I described, `std::result_of` just interprets it differently.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. I started decoding from wrong point and got confused.

Comment: Yes, that's what it would be in the real world. But that's **not** what it means when it's the argument type for `std::result_of`, which hijacks this notation to represent a callable type and its argument list.

Comment: @PeteBecker I thought that OP was confused about that declaration. I never heard of `std::result_of` (because I've learned C++ after C++11 came out, so I'm using just `decltype` and new features), thanks for your explanation of it. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't as simple as it looks.  `std::result_of` abuses the type system to smuggle in information about a function call so that it can figure out what the return type of that function call would be.

The argument to `std::result_of` has the form `Fty(T1, T2, ...)`, where `Fty` is a callable type and `T1` etc. are the types of the arguments that it is being called with. Given that information, `std::result_of` has a nested type named `type` that is a synonym for the return type of calling a callable type with the signature `Fty` with arguments of the given types. Phew, that's a mouthful.

So, in `result_of<void (*(int*))(int)>` there are two parts to the template argument. The first part is `void (*(int*))`, which is the callable type in question. In this case it's a pointer to function that takes `int*` and returns `void`. The second part is `(int)`, which is the type list for the proposed arguments.

So what that is saying is that `std::result_of` is being instantiated with a function whose type is `void (*(int*))` and with an argument list of `(int)`. And that's the problem, as you indicated: you can't pass an argument of type `int` to a function that takes an argument of type `int*`.

Aren't you glad you asked? (Incidentally, this is pretty low-level template hackery that's not needed any more; `decltype` is a much cleaner way to figure out the return type of a function call).

Comment: Yes, that was confusing at beginning. Thanks for explanation.