# C++ type definition unclear

Tags: c++, types

In the following C++ code what does `double (*) double` mean?
What kind of a return type is it?

```
auto get_fun(int arg) -> double (*)(double) // same as: double (*get_fun(int))(double)
{
    switch (arg)
    {
        case 1: return std::fabs;
        case 2: return std::sin;
        default: return std::cos;
    }
}
```

Comment: go c++11 all the way: `auto get_fun(int arg) -> auto (*)(double) -> double`

Comment: See also [How to interpret this C++ type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37844752/1314743) and the external [How to interpret complex C/C++ declarations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations).

Comment: @bolov that's obscene :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`double (*)(double)` it's a function pointer signature for a function that takes one `double` argument and returns `double`. Generally

```
X (*)(A, B, C)  // any number of args
```

is a pointer to function that takes args of types`(A, B, C)` and returns value of type `X`, e.g.

```
X my_func(A, B, C) {
    return X();  // assuming this makes sense
}
```

would be of the signature above.

So in your case `get_fun` is a function that returns a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`double (*)(double)` is type representing a pointer on function taking `double` and returning `double`.